# Create a three panel plot with one panel spanning 2 columns using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have following data:

```
    df <- data.frame("Stat" = c("Var1","Var1","Var1","Var1","Var1","Var2","Var2","Var2","Var2","Var2","Var2","Var2","Var2","Var2","Var2","Var2","Var2","Var2","Var2","Var2","Var2","Var2","Var2","Var2","Var2","Var3","Var3","Var3","Var3","Var3","Var3","Var3","Var3","Var3","Var3"),

"Value" = c(0,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),

"n" = c(33,120,223,63,20,17,28,33,22, 35,41,53,44,55,59,39,33, 46,30,29,23,21,14,6,18,7,29,50,80,86,91,83,35,34, 20))
```

What I wanted to do is to plot the above data as bar plot in one canvas but in three rows (1 columns x 3 rows) and each panel should contain plot for only one variable (Stat) eg. Var1 in first panel, Var2 in second and Var3 in the third panel, using the following code:

```
library(multipanelfigure)

fig1 <- multi_panel_figure(columns = 2, rows = 2, panel_label_type = "none")

# fit the plots on the panels
fig1 %<>%
  fill_panel(Var1Plot, column = 1, row = 1) %<>%
  fill_panel(Var2Plot, column = 2, row = 1) %<>%
  fill_panel(Var3Plot, column = 1:2, row = 2) 

fig1
```

Issue is how to get the Var1Plot, Var2Plot and Var3Plot so that these can be placed in respective panels above. I used the below code, but not able to get the results into above panels:

```
 library(tidyverse)
 df %>% ggplot(aes(x = Value, y = n)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') + facet_wrap(~ Stat)
```

Expected plot should look something like this :

[image]

Comment: It is unclear from your question what output you expect. How would this be different than using `facet_wrap(~ Stat, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)`? Perhaps you could provide a mock up in paint or preview?

Comment: @IanCampbell - added the referenced plot.... facet_wrap() is not the one that would print the plots into panles. I have tried already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach with `cowplot`.

```
library(cowplot)
figure.list <- map(unique(df$Stat), ~
  ggplot(data = subset(df, df$Stat == .x), aes(x = Value, y = n)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
  ggtitle(.x))

top <- plot_grid(figure.list[[1]], figure.list[[2]], ncol = 2)
bottom <- plot_grid(figure.list[[3]], ncol = 1)
plot_grid(top, bottom,
          ncol=1, rel_heights=c(1,1))
```

[image]

If you really want some to be `coord_flip`-ed, you could make the list manually:

```
figure.list <- list()
figure.list[[1]] <- ggplot(data = subset(df, df$Stat == "Var1"), aes(x = Value, y = n)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') + coord_flip()
figure.list[[2]] <- ggplot(data = subset(df, df$Stat == "Var2"), aes(x = Value, y = n)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') + coord_flip()
figure.list[[3]] <- ggplot(data = subset(df, df$Stat == "Var3"), aes(x = Value, y = n)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity')


top <- plot_grid(figure.list[[1]], figure.list[[2]], ncol = 2)
bottom <- plot_grid(figure.list[[3]], ncol = 1)
plot_grid(top, bottom,
          ncol=1, rel_heights=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Comment: just one more thing... how to get var names on each plot in this case?